# Soft reference and weak reference

Tags: java, android

I'm cursious about the soft and weak references in the Java environment. I have also read a bit about both topics. Just to sum up, the weak reference are as the name says, weak references to an object. This means that the reference to this object is easily collected by the `GC`. A weak reference is created this way:

```
WeakReference<SomeOtherRef> weakReference = new WeakReference(someOtherRef);
```

On the other hand a soft reference will stick around much longer than a weak reference. So my question is:

In my application, I have a custom adapter for a `ListView` This class will handle all the basic `ListView` stuff as handling clicks etc. When the user click on off the items in my list, a AsyncTask will be started.

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                LoadCase loadCase = new LoadCase(position, holder);
                loadCase.execute("");

            }
        });
```

For now I dont show any progressDialog, for one reason. The `context` object. My problem is that the `Activity` which will initialize the CustomAdapter holds many object, and I have to pass a reference to the `Activity Context` in order to show a `ProgressDialog`, this **will** cause memory leaks, yes, I have tried. Is it safe to apply the Weak/Soft reference to deal with this? A `WeakReference` can be, at some time, null..this will cause a `NullPointerException` when I try to initialize my `ProgressDialog`.

Comment: I dont think you want WeakReferences or anything like that to dialogs or UI code etc.  These have known life cycles and should be managed as such.  Normally you use WeakReferences for lazy initialised caches and the like.

Comment: Use normal strong reference instead..

Comment: @NeilWightman using normal references would prevent the GC to collect them if the activity is destroyed (for example for an orientation change).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a good idea to use a `WeakReference` here, because the activity could be destroyed. You have to check if it's null each time that you want to use it to avoid a `NullPointerException`. If it's null, it means that the activity has been destroyed, and thus it usually doesn't make sense to show a `ProgressDialog`.

Of course, the activity could be destroyed and recreated (for example because of an orientation change). If the `AsyncTask` takes long, this could have the problem that the progress bar is no longer shown. But the problem here would be using an `AsyncTask` for a long task, they are intended for short tasks.

Also, remember that if you subclass `AsyncTask` as an inner class in the `Activity` class, it will have a strong reference to the Activity, so using a `WeakReference` would be useless.

Comment: Thanks for a perfect answer. The AsyncTask job is just to load two BitMaps from a SQLite DB. This takes around 1.5 - 2.0 seconds.